# Laravel updateOrCreate - not updating correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my DB `files`, `file_types` and `post_files` and when I am saving file type first to my DB like this:

```
private function findOrCreateFileType($fileType)
{
    return $fileType = FileType::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $fileType,
        'slug' => str_slug($fileType, '-')
    ]);
}
```

Then after that I am saving a file to DB and updating 'content_files' table as well like this:

```
        $file = File::updateOrCreate([
            'cms_id' => $inventoryRemoteId,
            'file_name' => $file->post_name,
            'file_path' => $file->guid,
        ], [
            'file_type_id' => $fileType->id,
            'file_extension' => pathinfo($file->guid)['extension'],
            'file_size' => $fileInfo['Content-Length']
        ]);

        PostFile::updateOrCreate([
          'file_id' => $file->id,
          'post_id' => $contentId,
        ],[
          'file_type_id' => $fileType->id,
        ]);
```

The problem that I have is when I am saving a post that has for example 2 files of 2 different types, for example an `attachment` and a `feature image` then it is correctly saving in to the `file_types` table:

```
   ID  |  name
   --------------------
   1   |  feature_image
   --------------------
   2   |  attachment
```

But, then when I am saving to `files` table, it is not saving correctly since it is giving the last type to every file for that post:

```
   ID  |  file_type_id  |  name
   --------------------
   1   |       1        |  feature_image file name
   --------------------
   2   |       1        |  attachment file name
```

So, since I am first saving `feature-image` and then `attachments` it is for some reason updating the `file_type_id` of the `feature-image` in the `files` table, as well as in the `post_files` table. What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check `$inventoryRemoteId`, `$file->post_name`, `$file->guid` values? They may be same.

Comment: ```$file->post_name``` is different, first file ```post_name = screen-shot-2017-05-08-at-10-35-54```, second file ```post_name = screen-shot-2017-07-06-at-14-36-32```

Comment: Did you check them before the `$file` returned or after the `$file` returned?

Comment: I meant when did you check them, before you call `File::updateOrCreate` or after that?

Comment: I have checked it in the DB, and have checked the first file, which is the feature_image, and it is giving me the same post->name as it is saved in the DB

Comment: how are you initialising `$fileType` in the second block?

Comment: I am calling a function to get the ```$fileType = $this->findOrCreateFileType($fileTypeInfo);``` and I am getting the correct ```$fileType``` for the first file which is the ```feature-image```, but later it obviously gets overwritten for some reason, with the ```$fileType``` of the new file